# Pandas column transform into 1D array

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to preprocess the data frame for the decision tree creation but getting the error about the dimension:

`y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1, 1460) instead.`

I've tried to use `values = df_train[col].unique().flatten()` but the error was the same.

The code is the following:

```
for col in df_train.columns:
    values = df_train[col].unique()
    new_col = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    new_col.fit([values])
    col_num = df_train.columns.get_loc(col)
    df_train[:,col_num] = new_col.transform(df_train[:,col_num])
```

Example of columns:

| Colour | Area |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 230 |
| Yellow | 400 |

Thank you!

Comment: It would be better if you provide a sample of the output.

Comment: Did you try df_train.to_numpy().flatten() or df_trian.values.flatten()?  You can also use .tolist() at the end if you need it as a Python list e.g. df_train.values.flatten().tolist().

Comment: You can try  1) `df.T` to transpose your dataframe 2) if (1) doesn't work, use `df.to_numpy()` then use `.reshape` on the output with `reshape(1460,)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code fixed (pass 'values' without an outside list, also use .iloc for integer indexing):

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

df_train = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cactus'],
                  'B': ['gray', 'black', 'black', 'green']})
print(df_train)

        A      B
0     cat   gray
1     dog  black
2     cat  black
3  cactus  green
```

```py
for col in df_train.columns:
    values = df_train[col].unique()
    new_col = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    new_col.fit(values)
    col_num = df_train.columns.get_loc(col)
    df_train.iloc[:,col_num] = new_col.transform(df_train.iloc[:,col_num])
    
print(df_train)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  0
2  1  0
3  0  1
```

But this is way too complicated. It's better to use [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html):

### Proper way

```
ord_enc = preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()
X_train = ord_enc.fit_transform(df_train)
print(X_train)

[[1. 2.]
 [2. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

OrdinalEncoder is designed for features transformation, unlike LabelEncoder, which is for target transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure because you have not shared the full output of the code, but I think, if you take transpose of the result of `df_train[col].unique()` which will convert it from `[1,1046)` to `(1046, 1)`. It is my guess that `1046` should be your number of samples and `1` should be number of columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for col in df_train.columns:
    values = df_train[col].unique()
    new_col = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    new_col.fit(values)
    col_num = df_train.columns.get_loc(col)
    df_train[:,col_num] = new_col.transform(df_train[:,col_num])
```